# How to make association and relationship with raw queries in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I tried to use by passing query as first parameter and options as second parameter.But did not get solution.

```
sequelize
.query('SELECT * FROM users', {
    include: [
        {
            model: Projects,
            required: true,
        },
    ],
})
.then(projects => {
    res.json(projects);
});
```

Comment: King Khan  Please format your code

Comment: Looking for a solution.